# Update Global Variables

Tags: plugin-development, globals, updates

I've got a custom plugin where I'm trying to update a global variable. The variable field type is of type `Entry`

I'm getting the set using `getSetByHandle` then using `getContent` on the set. However, when I do a `count` on the retrieved content, the value is 1. I have about 10 global variables so would've expected a `count` of 10.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, so a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Update**

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
$global_set = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('globalVariables');
$selected_poll = craft()->entries->getEntryById($poll_id);
$content = $global_set->getContent();
craft()->globals->saveSet($globalSet);
```

**Update**

I've also tried the following, with no luck:

```
$globalSet = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('tempSet');
$content = $globalSet->getContent();
$content->currentItem = craft()->entries->getEntryById($itemID);
$globalSet->setContent($content);
craft()->globals->saveContent($globalSet);
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code you are using to grab the Global from the DB, edit it, and then save? We could better assist in a solution that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I was going about it completely the wrong way. As the field in question is an `Entry` type, I needed to use the `Relations Service`

```
$globalSet = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('[globalSetHAndle]');
$selectedField = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('[fieldHandle]');
craft()->relations->saveRelations($selectedField, $globalSet, array($entryId));
```

Passing `null` instead of `array($entryId)` will clear the relation values